# I need an Java API for develop ICQ and Yahoo Client

Tags: java, yahoo, icq

I currently want to implement my own Yahoo and ICQ client in Java.
I did search in SOF and found openymsg and joscarlib.
But I have problems:
1. openymsg works, but there are Warning while login :

```
Jan 21, 2012 10:41:05 PM org.openymsg.network.Session removeSessionListener
WARNING: SessionListener not found to be removed.
java.lang.Throwable
    at org.openymsg.network.Session.removeSessionListener(Session.java:270)
    at org.openymsg.network.Session.resetData(Session.java:3688)
    at org.openymsg.network.Session.login(Session.java:337)
    at org.openymsg.network.Session.login(Session.java:292)
    at imTypes.Yahoo.startListen(Yahoo.java:47)
    at imServer.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

But I did add SessionListener above the login : yahooSession.addSessionListener(this);   ( this class extends SessionAdapter ofcourse).

And How to disable  Logging ?

1. joscarLib seem doen't work OR I my code is wrong. Please verify that joscardLib still  works and I will try to fix it. If it doesn't work, Please suggest me another Lib.

Thank you very much

Comment: You need to split your question to two: 1) What are available ICQ/AIM libraries, 2) How to deal with your exception.

Answer (score 1):

I have found:

- jck2k: Last Update: 2009-07-17 http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcq2k/
- ExeQ: Last Update: 2009-07-17  http://sourceforge.net/projects/exeqlib/
- jOscar - Last Update: 2010-10-23 http://sourceforge.net/projects/ooimlib/a
- Jimm  Java ME - Last Update: 2011  http://sourceforge.net/projects/jimm/
- jOscar - probably different one: http://joust.kano.net/